# C# application with access database won't work on 64 bit windows 7

Tags: c#, ms-access

I made C# application for my friend which has connection to access database (mdb file). I have developed application on my computer with win7 x86 installed. My friend had XP and it worked perfectly, but now he installed win7 x64 and application doesn't work. In fact, application starts and behave regular, but cannot connect to database... Database too can be opened with access, but my application cannot connect to it.
What can be a problem? How to make my application works on both operating systems?

regards,

Vajda

Comment: Which error does your friend receive when trying to run it? He or she might not have the version of the .Net framework that the application requires, or a number of other issues.

**EDIT:**

Actually, it probably wouldn't be a framework issue if the application runs but does not connect. I would still like to know the error message though.

Comment: Well, I used my own custom message for all connection issues, so it's not much of help. And currently I don't have time to go there to see problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask your friend to download and install the following file:

- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en)

and make sure he picks the 64-bit version there (AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe).

By default there is no 64-bit ODBC/OLEDB driver for Access installed, but the 2010 version should work for 2007 databases as well.

You could probably also configure your program to be built for the x86 target. That would run the program as a 32-bit program, even on 64-bit OS.

Comment: in reply to your comment on my deleted answer, I am sure your set are a better idea in this case, the runtime is an advantage if you wish to build and distribute Access applications.

Comment: Ah, so the ones you linked to are for full blown Access applications, not just for accessing the MDB from another program. Gotcha, nice to know about it, though I hope I never have to touch an Access application ever again :P

Comment: ut the 2010 version should work for 2007 databases as well. Well, this is an 2003 mdb database, I hope you think this will work too. :) I will sent this new built version to my friend and link to redistributable. I'll tell what heappened.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the .Net CLR is trying to fire the app up in 64bit mode by default on his new win7 box and this might be causing some issues with the referenced assemblies.

The first thing I would try is to change the Platform target of the application (go to Project properties in Visual Studio for the application) to x86 (from Any CPU) to force the application to run in 32bit mode.

If this works, you will have narrowed down your problem.

Then, after building the project, look in the bin folder to see which assemblies are being copied to the output folder.  If you see any System.Data... or any other .Net assemblies that are already contained in the GAC, you'll want to delete these and then try to fire it up.  This will force the application to use GAC assemblies written for 64bit use.